# Spring applicationcontextaware use confirmation

Tags: spring

In an interview, I have been asked a Question:

In spring, what is the use of an ApplicationContextAware interface ?

1. Performing Dependency injection
2. Makes bean aware of the container
3. Both of these
4. None of these

As per my knowledge, as well as per few articles , I think Option 2 is correct.

Please let me know if ApplicationContextAware interface also helps in Performing Dependency injection.

Answer (score 0):

According to Docs, Its main/only goal is that class which is implementing this interface requires access to a set of collaborating beans.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContextAware.html

Answer (score 0):

I think the interface's name is self explanatory, so yes it makes the bean aware of the container.
The dependency injection is performed by the framework through multiple ways, but most of them use the `@Autowired` annotation, so you could start reading about it.